# Express router post route not found

Tags: node.js, express, post, jwt, http-status-code-404

So I've been following some tutorials trying to get an api with JWT authentication and Express working. But the post routes keep returning 404 not found. I've tried adding a GET route which does work. (I did select the right type of request in POSTMAN) Any ideas?

```
// /routes/userRoute.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const userController = require('../controllers/userController');

router.post('/register', userController.create);
router.post('/authenticate', userController.authenticate);

module.exports = router;

// app.js
const express = require('express'),
app = express(),
port = process.env.PORT || 4000,
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'),
cors = require('cors'),
user = require('./models/userModel');

const auth = require('./auth/verifyToken'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoutes');

// mongoose instance connection url connection
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/frits',{useNewUrlParser:true});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.json({"Welkom" : "Frits API"});
});

app.use('/user', userRoutes);

app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.status(404).send({url: req.originalUrl + ' not found'})
});

app.listen(port);

console.log('frits API server started on: ' + port);
```

Comment: which post route?

Comment: Both router.post routes in userRoutes.js

Comment: @MarkKoudstaal just to confirm, are you trying to POST request on `/user/register` and `/user/authenticate`, not just `/register` and `/authenticate`? Your code seems fine. And what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: I have got it working now. It seems to be a problem with my reverse proxy or something. Not sure what the exact problem is but for some reason it will only accept my request when it is https. I got it working by making an https request with ajax from my front end.